# Compute transform of vertex animated mesh

Tags: python, animation

I have a mesh made of different components which is animated using a MeshSequenceCache modifier. This mesh comes from an alembic file.

[image]

Each one of the different mesh components doesn't deform, so it should be possible to convert the MeshSequence into a keyframe animation, animating the transform.

For that, I would first need to separate the original mesh into different meshes, which I am not being able to do so, I think because of the MeshSequenceCache modifier.

Once I have each mesh animated separately, I would need to find the proper transform, which I have no idea how to do.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I cant write some python if needed to perform this

Comment: There is a missing piece of information, unrecoverable, which is the origin of rotation.  You could convert to a keyframe animation, consisting of a combination of translation + rotation, but the precise mix is going to depend on what you choose as the origin of rotation, which has to be a manual-ish decision (center of geometry is probably not right.)  You can bake to keyframes by marking vertices with vertex groups and using those to copy location, damped track, locked track the orientation onto empties, followed, potentially, by baking that action with visual + clear constraints.

Comment: I dont really care about the initial rotation, only the relative rotation between different keyframes of the components, so I think the initial rotation can be set to whatever I want

Comment: If that was a response to me, you're right, the initial rotation doesn't matter, but I wasn't talking about that.  I was talking about which location it rotates about: the center of rotation.  This is not information that is contained in the mesh or its animation.

Comment: @Nathan I think I can just select the center of the object as rotation center. In any case, this data will be used to provide transform and bind pose matrices to an engine, so I think it still doesn't matter the center of rotation, as its going to be cancelled, no?

Comment: Whether it matters depends on your reasons for doing this.  Output on keyframes will be identical regardless of choice of origin, but it's still something that has to be chosen and can't be determined from the mesh.  Interpolation between keyframes will be different depending on choice of origin.

Comment: The reason for doing this is that I have a tetrahedra mesh and I want to find the vertices of my tetrahedra mesh which are inside this bones and move them as if they are attached to the bone (to set boundary conditions of a mechanical simulation). To do so I was expecting to apply the relative transform from the rest pose (in the iamge) to an animated pose (some frame)

Answer (score 0):

So first, there *is* information missing, which is the center of rotation.  You can make keyframes from this, but you cannot make *one unique set* of keyframes-- without a center of rotation, there are an infinite number of keyframes you could make that represent this particular animation.  These animations will be identical at keyframed locations, but not in-between-- interpolation will differ.  Whether that matters depends on your reasons for doing this, but if the goal is to transfer this animation onto a different mesh, retaining editable keyframes, that's an important part of the equation.

That said, you can make an animation out of this, and it's not too much trouble for a few hand bones.

For each separate element in the alembic: Enter edit on your alembic mesh and select three (non collinear) vertices on a single element.  Three and only three.  In object mode, create an empty.  Parent that empty to your alembic with vertex (triangle) mode.

When you have done this for all elements-- each element has a vertex parented empty-- select all of your empties and use a bake action operation.  Set this bake action to clear parents and use visual transform.  Defaults should be on "object" which is correct.

Your empties now contain the transforms for your separate elements.  The origin of rotation used for this transform is the location of the empty, which isn't necessarily the origin of rotation used for the original animation.  As I mentioned, that information cannot be recovered from the alembic.

Elements of this process could be scripted, but scripting it would probably take longer than just doing it, at least on the mesh you're showing.

Comment: When I set the parent as triangle, how do I specify the 3 vertices that it must use?

Comment: That is why you select the three vertices on the alembic-- to indicate which vertices.

Comment: Okay, misunderstood. I thought I had to create vertex groups with my selections

Comment: That was my first plan, in comments, but when I got around to writing a real answer, I realized vertex parenting would work fine, and is less trouble.

Comment: I am not sure it is working. I enter edit mode on the alembic mesh and select three vertices. I exit edit mode and create an empty and parent it to the alembic mesh with vertex (triangle) mode. The empty remains at the origin, shouldn't it go to one of the vertices location?

Comment: No, it should remain where it is, regardless.  It has its own separate transform.  Where you put it is an arbitrary choice.  If you want to put at the location of one of those vertices, you can.  To see whether it's working, all you do is watch it move with the animation of that element.

Comment: Yes, it moves with the animation of the element, but its difficult to say if its having the same transform. Well, of course its not having the same transform, so this solution doesn't allow me to extract the transform of the bones (given some reference frame)

Comment: Exactly, because you don't know the origin of rotation.  You don't know where the head of the bone is.

Comment: If I can provide that info, what can I do to improve this result?

Comment: You provide that info based on your choice of where you put the empty.  Prior to baking the animation.